# How do I place properly formatted JSON in an http POST body?

Tags: json, powershell, actionable-notification

I am generating Outlook Actionable Messages via Powershell. I need to put JSON in the body of an HTTP post request like this example for Microsoft's site (please note the example is just above this link, I can't copy and paste for some reason, so please scroll up a little after you click it)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/adaptive-card#reporting-actionhttp-execution-success-or-failure

I've noticed that the. "body": "{{nameInput.value}}"  portion needs to be JSON but escape characters are required or it does not work. Is there a good way in Powershell to generate this output? I have created Powershell objects and used convertto-json, which creates JSON but not with the appropriate escape characters.

Here's an example of an object created in PowerShell

```
$appointment = [pscustomobject]@{
        Subject = "Foo"
}
```

Converting that to JSON gives me this:

```
$appointment | ConvertTo-Json
{
    "Subject":  "Foo"
}
```

However, when I put this in the http POST body, I need something like this:

```
"body": 
     "{
           \"subject\":\"foo\"
      }",
```

Note the escaping around the quotation marks.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post an example where convert to-Jason gives the wrong result, and what result you expected instead?

Comment: Sorry - was posting from my phone - i meant ConvertTo-Json, obvs...

Comment: Sure, here's an example object I made in PowerShell:

Comment: I added it to the original post above.

Comment: If "body" is a string which contains escaped Json you can just ConvertTo-String again ```$appointment | ConvertTo-Json | ConvertTo-Json``` gives you the string you said you need. However, you might want to check whether the body should be structured json instead - e.g. ```"body": { "subject": "foo" }``` in which case you'll need to add your $appointment into your message object before calling ConvertTo-Json on the whole thing.